# Using await for non CPU intensive task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have something like this:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Creating Foo");
    Foo result = new Foo();

    DoSomethingAsync();

    System.Console.WriteLine("Returning Foo");
    return result;
}


private async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    // The following task takes a long time, but is not CPU intensive
    await TaskEx.Run(() =>
    {
         // code lives here... removed for this example
    });
}
```

Since I don't hit the CPU much, I don't need a thread. What can I use instead of Run to avoid the creation of a thread?

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but if you want to do something asynchronous, you have to have a separate thread from which to accomplish that work in an asynchronous manner.  If you keep it on the same thread, it blocks and is therefore synchronous.

Comment: My understanding of the Async library was that it used the windows message pump to create callbacks and manage code execution in such a way that gave the appearance of threads (async execution) without actually using threads. That is, unless you use the "run" method of a task, at which point you would get a thread. Run is only recommended for CPU intensive operations.

The PDC 2010 talk given by Anders Hejlsberg explained this well:
http://bit.ly/bBGOfV

Comment: Why not just extract the code in your TaskEx.Run(), and call the await statement on that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the intent of the Task Asynchrony Pattern here.  What you're doing is probably better handled by [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) which will reuse a worker thread from the process's pool, only creating one if necessary.

The TAP allows you to break a task into "chunks" of work that can be processed incrementally, but it does not directly provide a means to say "this is a background task".

Comment: Hmmm, okay, but what if I don't need a background task?

I don't want to get into all the details of the work my task is doing (talks to a 3rd party COM lib, gets messy, etc.), but needless to say, for the most part, it's doing a lot of nothing. It's not pure web-service/network stuff, so I can't use the built in methods like DownloadStringTaskAsync.

It does, however, send out a request and blocks while it waits for a response. Perfect thing to use the Async lib for, right? I guess what I'm trying to do is build my own method similar to "DownloadStringTaskAsync".

Comment: Actually, no.  The TAP is **only** good for cases in which you can actually return instead of blocking; the compiler's `async` method modifier simply instructs it to transform your code into this style.  If you're calling into third party blocking code that was not written with `async/await` in mind, you have to use a thread.

Comment: Your right. This new framework really had me confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task that you're doing. Since you say that it doesn't use a lot of CPU, I'll assume the task takes a long time because it's waiting for other events. So, you'll need to design your task to register callbacks for those events, where each callback completes quickly on the main thread, but isn't triggered until the event you're awaiting actually occurs.